# How to split a div?

Tags: html

how do I split a div into two rows so I can add two grids !!!! The grid which I'm using is of TMS .

Comment: Please explain in many more word what you want. How about registering and giving some feedback points too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

divs don't really work like that (splitting into rows and columns).  if you have a div, just put both grids inside.

```
 <div>
      <control1/>
      <control2/>
 </div>
```

if you need to add a line break in between, either set control2's style to something that will break ("float:left;clear:left") or add a 
 in between.

**Edit**

In response to your comment to another answer

> OK , I actually wanted the two grids in one div , I mean one grid in right, other in the left

I suspect you mean you want 2 columns, not 2 rows.

```
  |<--  column -->|<-- column -->|
  +---------------+--------------+ 
  |               |              |  ^
  |               |              | row
  |               |              |  v
  +---------------+--------------+
```

In this case, there's a couple ways you can handle alignment. one way is to float the two controls --

```
<div>
    <control1 style='float:left' />
    <control2 style='float:left' />
</div>
```

you could also use inline-block, with possibly better results, but it would take a bit of fiddling. see [this link](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) for a treatise on aligning elements with inline-block

Comment: Well, they split into rows pretty easily. :-)

Comment: Is there a way, in which you can force it to show 2 columns & 1 row, even if the data in both columns together exceeds page width? I am OK with horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't amazingly clear, but if I'm reading you right, the easiest way is to put two divs inside your div. So instead of:

```
<div><!-- grid stuff here --></div>
```

you'd do:

```
<div>
    <div><!-- stuff for first grid here --></div>
    <div><!-- stuff for second grid here --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK , I actually wanted the two grids in one div , I mean one grid in right, other in the left .....but for now the grid is appearing down.
Its same as you split in a table with two rows !! same as that I need to split a div and add two grids side by side . Hope you get my point . Thanking you all in advance for your awesome support and replies .

Answer (score 1):

I found best solution to your question. The best way is to float your divs inside of your main div.

example:

```
<div align="left"><div style="float:left">hello</div><div style="float:left">bye</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two child`<div>` elements to the `<div>` you want to split?

Answer (score 0):

surely these link will gonna help you
http://methvin.com/splitter/index.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141040/jquery-splitter-change-to-vertical-splitter-on-button-click
http://methvin.com/splitter/hsplitter.html
cheers